# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'splitlines' while sending email notification in django

Tags: django, email, django-rest-framework, smtp, tuples

I am trying to send email notifications using the SMTP Gmail host. But when I try to send user information in the message field, it shows the above error.

This is my booking view:

```
class BookingCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes= [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Booking.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookingSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # user = self.request.user
        package = get_object_or_404(Package, pk= self.kwargs['pk'])
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user,package=package)
        # data = self.request.data
        name = serializer.data['name']
        email = serializer.data['email']
        phone = serializer.data['phone']

        send_mail('New booking ',(name,email,phone), email , ['example@gmail.com'],
                  fail_silently=False)
```

This is my serializer:

```
class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # blog = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'bookedfor']
        # fields = '__all__'
```

How to solve this??

Comment: The second argument of [**`send_mail(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#send-mail) is **`message`** which is supposed to be a ***string***

Comment: Then, how to send user's details like name, phone and email ?? Is there any other way??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
send_mail('New booking ',f'{name},{email},{phone}', email , ['saroj.aakashlabs@gmail.com'],
              fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.